# Erro Deploy Heroku - Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

Estou iniciando um projeto de uma aplicação em Java, e estou realizando a configuração dos ambientes antes de começar a implementação. Porém, quando fui criar o app no Heroku e realizar o Deploy através do repositório do projeto no meu GIT, esse erro aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que eu entendi, não encontrou meu arquivo pom.xml no meu projeto, mas ele foi criado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou procurando algumas soluções, mas não encontrei nada por enquanto.

Comment: Poderia colocar, por favor, a estrutura toda de diretório do seu projeto no servidor? De qualquer maneira vou enviar uma solução para alguns casos que já vi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em alguns casos, o problema é que o `diretório git` é um diretório externo e a pasta do projeto (com código propriamente e que contém o `pom.xml`) está dentro desse mesmo diretório git "raiz".

Exemplo:

```
- diretorioGit
  |___diretorioDoProjeto
           |____codigo...
           |____pom.xml
```

Isso é um dos tipos de problema que já vi acontecer. Mas pra confirmar se é o seu caso, precisamos ver a estrutura de diretório do seu projeto, conforme solicitei no comentário na pergunta.

A solução para esse caso poderia ser mover o diretório `.git` e o arquivo `.gitignore` para o diretorio `diretorioDoProjeto`.